# How to create a firebase dynamic link with the REST API

Tags: http, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to generate a dynamic link in firebase using the REST API. I've tried following instruction on the following page of the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters

My apologies in advance for bad formatting, but my request looks something like this:

POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=

with headers:

Content-Type: application/json

and body:

```js
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo":{
    "domainUriPrefix":"https://<myDomain>.page.link/",
    "link":"https://www.google.com/",
    "androidInfo":{
      "androidPackageName":"com.<companyName>.<appname>"
    }   
  }
}
```

The response i get is:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid Dynamic Link domain: '' or Domain Uri Prefix: 'https://<myDomain>.page.link/'. Expecting exactly one. Dynamic Link Domain isPresent = false, Domain URI prefix isPresent = false,  [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

My firebase project has a the .page.link domain registered within the project. In the dynamic links section of the firebase project it does show up. I've tested creating links in the firebase console and i've even been able to manually make dynamic short-links using the react-native-firebase package so i'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with my project.

Comment: can you share your exact dynamic link prefix that you're using? also, can you try this one?
"domainUriPrefix":"https://<myDomain>.page.link",

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot have / at the end of domainuriprefix. Can you try removing it?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another solution.
In my case a simple white space in front of 'https' was the trigger.

```
"message": "Invalid Dynamic Link domain: '' or Domain Uri Prefix: ' https://[...]'
```

Comment: Oh man! this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You do need to add the `https://` portion to your `domainUriPrefix` ->

```
  {
      "dynamicLinkInfo":{
        "domainUriPrefix":"<myDomain>.page.link",
        "link":"https://www.google.com/",
        "androidInfo":{
          "androidPackageName":"com.<companyName>.<appname>"
        }   
      }
   }
```